# Why does this.id not replace the selector in $(selector).html in this script?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am new to this programming world and what I think seems logical is not working.  I am trying to get different data sources into different divs.  I have looked at all the different answers listed on this site, however the levels of answers are sometime beyond the problem that I have with script.   I would love to understand why this does not work more than just getting an answer.

Why can I use the `$(this.id)` method to load id into div? `$('#div_1').html($(this.id, resp).html())`

Why does `this.id` not replace the selector in `$(selector).html` in this script?

```
$(function () {
    $(this.id).click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        console.log(id);
        var postData = ''; // you can send any data to ajax file.
        var channels = this.id
        $('#div_1 , #div_2').html(''); // placeholder
        $.ajax({
            url: 'info.php', // your ajax file
            type: 'post',
            data: postData,
            success: function (resp) {
                $('#div_1').html($(this.id, resp).html());
                $('#div_2').html($('#inner_2', resp).html());
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

body

```
<a href="#" onClick="return false" id="01">01</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" id="02">02</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" id="03">03</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" id="04">04</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return false" id="05">05</a>
```

PHP file

```
<id="01">this is 01</>
<id="02">this is 02</>
<id="03">this is 03</>
<id="04">this is 04</>
<id="05">this is 05</>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` means the current object. `$( function() { $(this.id)` doesn't work because there is no `this` [object] yet to say this on.

In `$('#div_1').html($(this.id, resp).html())` there is already a `this` [object], namely, the `'#div_1` and that is why it works!

Comment: My object would be the id selector i assume in this case.  Is the this.id not a object?

Comment: In the case of the script: Is the id any object with $this? Or how can I make this an object?